# Defining forward-position for Kinect Rig

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I need to figure out the direction in Worldspace my Kinect rig is facing.
The rig itself is just some Gameobjects placed in worldspace. They are not related to each other. The elements of the rig are always the same name, so it should be possible to determine the direction by this.

[image: Kinect Rig]

I see the logic how to solve the problem, but I can't see how to do it in world space, adapting the x and z correctly.

[image: Logic to Solve]

Comment: Plum3r, note that there is a HUGE problem with your diagram ("logic to solve").  That is a 2D diagram  :)  So there is no chirality.  You have to add an "upwards" direction, or it is meaningless.  If you think about it, "upwards" is very simple - from spineBase to head!  Enjoy

Comment: Yeah , the up direction is no Problem. I tried a different approach:
I create Gameobject between Left Hip and Right Hip. I Let the new Object look at the Left hip, so i know that the right side of my Object must be the forward direction.

It works fine except, that kinect doesn´t really detect my real direction correctly....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want the cross product of **A** a line from the left hip to the right hip, and, **B** a line from the left hip to the head.

You code will look something like this:

```
Vector3 A = hipRight - hipLeft
Vector3 B = head - helpLeft (or, ideally, head - spineBase)

Vector3 solution = Vector3.Cross(A, B).normalized
```

Obviously if you do AXB for something like this, and it's pointing backwards, just change to BXA.

---

• Don't forget Unity is left-handed.

• Tip.  Nobody can remember "which way" crosses point!  Here's the diagram:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html

[image]

Comment: That would give me the "up" direction.
I need the "forward" direction, in order to rotate a player toward that direction.

Comment: I can absolutely assure you that it gives the forward direction  :)

Comment: I will try to figure it out and post the result here.

Comment: hi @Plum3r - heh, no need to figure it out.  I've given you the code above.  It's a very standard problem in game physics.  Enjoy!

Comment: also @Plum3r be aware that some 3D engineers prefer to use the shoulders rather than hips.  it's an "open question" exactly "which way" a human is "pointing".

Comment: Thx for your help, it helped me a lot.

As described above, I first need to fix other Stuff, so this thread is solved for me :)